# Multiple Magento stores need to be visable at multiple domains

Tags: magento, iis, dns

I have an installation of Magento with multiple stores, which need to be displayed at different domains.

For example.

magento1.com - needs to be visible at current domain
magento1.com/store1 - needs to be visible at store1.com
magento1.com/store2 - needs to be visible at store2.com

I have the domains and have tried to set it up - but for some reason can't get it to work.
I'm running IIS on server.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup